# Vertical align span next to the float select in table

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

How to vertical align middle text in first column when select is float:right next to the text in span. This elements must be in div. I can use line-height but it doesn't exist when text is longer.

[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/0t71v5h4/4/)

[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtQOF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these css rules to your css code

```
td > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```